# GPU load is around 20% when using OpenCL on GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu

My question is, assuming the input buffer is an image and its pixels are being processed in the kernel, when we clenqueueNDRangeKernel a task on the GPU, does the task gets divided and processed by all the compute units ? And if so, should the GPU utilization reach 100% every time it comes into action? And if not so, can you please point me to where I can clarify what percent of GPU is utilized when ?

Comment: It depends to a large extent how many work items you are submitting, and how much compute unit occupancy these work items achieve. The more work items you enqueue, and the less private (register) and local (shared) memory they use, the higher your utilisation will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the task gets divided and processed by all the compute units ?

Yes, unless you use subdevices, or your WorkItem count is too low.

> should the GPU utilization reach 100% every time it comes into action?

Depends on what you mean by "utilization". There will be no idle compute units, but how much some parts (memory/texture units, vector/scalar units) of CU will be used depends entirely on your kernel.